# How to pass specific fields of the output of one chain to the second chain using langchain

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

### TL;DR:

I have a sequence of 4 `LLMChains`. I want to orchestrate then into a routable chain. The first two chain uses `PydanticOutputParser` so their outputs are in a dict format.

The simple overview should be:

```
(input) -> Chain1 -> (C1out.text_found) -> Chain2 -> if (C2out.value) == 1 -> Chain3 -> FinalOutput
                                                  -> else                  -> Chain4 -> FinalOutput
```

**However I can't find a way to pass only the "text_found" field of the first output to the second chain.** Given that it's a dictionary.

---

The output of `Chain1` is a dict with multiple fields. Only the "text_found" is needed for the prompt in of `Chain2`. At the `FinalOutput` I need to get all the fields from `Chain1`, so I can't remove the other fields.

I've tried and researched extensively, but here is one of

```
overall_chain = SequentialChain(
    chains=[CHAIN1, CHAIN2],
    input_variables=["source", "field", "full_text"],
    output_variables=["text_found", "confidence", "classification"],
    verbose=True
)
```

This will raise

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for SequentialChain
Missing required input keys: {'text_found'}, only had {...
```

However, I don't have this variable to input yet, as it is part of the CHAIN1 output.